# dyld[2179]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError

Tags: flutter

Here is my error, it is a Flutter app communicating with a BLE peripheral. The app has been working fine for almost a year, now I can not even get the app to start when running through Xcode.

Thinking this may be related to the iOS and Xcode update yesterday

```
dyld[2179]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError
  Referenced from: <D26B8D55-5052-3B29-A2D1-64F3A74A6628> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/54180268-0E54-41B4-A5ED-E03F662FAE86/Runner.app/Runner
  Expected in:     <6DD9F429-0BD2-3581-B55F-23B9A86E1CC2> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/54180268-0E54-41B4-A5ED-E03F662FAE86/Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_blue_plus.framework/flutter_blue_plus
```

Comment: check if there is connectivity package you have used or not. Replaced with connectivity_plus plugin. and update your Ble package with latest one .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by upgrading FlutterBluePlus flutter plugin to 1.15.8

Comment: Updating FlutterBluePlus to the latest stable release and adapting your code to it should solve this issue. However, as LSpeer said, downgrading XCode is also a viable workaround. 
However, if you upgrade your MacOS to Sonoma, you can't use XCode 14.3.1.

Comment: Wasted all day fighting certificates, looking at logs, even tweaking CI/CD thinking the problem were dependencies in my local env. Upgrading the plugin solved the issue. Thanks @kbessemer !

Comment: This is great answer . And also check if there is connectivity package you have used or not. Replaced with connectivity_plus plugin .

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue, also right after Xcode updated.

I uninstalled Xcode and downloaded Xcode 14.3.1 from here https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ and my app is working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Happens after MacOS Sonoma and Xcode version 15 update. Only Flutter Blue Plus package is affected and cause this
Xcode runtime error:

```
dyld`:
    0x1b6bbec24 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x1b6bbec28 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1b6bbec2c <+8>:  b.lo   0x1b6bbec48               ; <+36>
    0x1b6bbec30 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1b6bbec34 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1b6bbec38 <+20>: bl     0x1b6b62de4               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1b6bbec3c <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1b6bbec40 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1b6bbec44 <+32>: ret    
    0x1b6bbec48 <+36>: ret    
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT



dyld[2347]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError
  Referenced from: <8AE94F1E-06C4-3C99-9A44-090D6815742D> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/25DB5D90-EDA4-4795-A29B-9A207F7F35E3/Runner.app/Runner
  Expected in:     <7E6D03A8-D9E7-3784-A3D5-FDC3005A1E64> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/25DB5D90-EDA4-4795-A29B-9A207F7F35E3/Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_blue_plus.framework/flutter_blue_plus
```

Note that, Xcode cannot detect the issue and app can be archived and released to TestFlight and AppStore. App will crash on startup page when installed from TestFlight or AppStore.

The solution is either to update Flutter Blue Plus to ^1.15.8 as mentioned above or MacOS + Xcode should be downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

**Errors**

1. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT; 0 _abortwith_payload
2. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT; 5 start
3. Symbol not found: (*OBJC_CLASS*$_Reachability)

**Error Log**

```
dyld[2089]: Symbol not found: (_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability)
  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FFB16420-F16D-4881-804D-1E84FFB5F725/Runner.app/Frameworks/connectivity.framework/connectivity'
  Expected in: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FFB16420-F16D-4881-804D-1E84FFB5F725/Runner.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability'
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001032e72cc dyld`__abort_with_payload + 8
dyld`:
->  0x1032e72cc <+8>:  b.lo   0x1032e72e8               ; <+36>
    0x1032e72d0 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1032e72d4 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1032e72d8 <+20>: bl     0x1032ad64c               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

**Reason of error**

In my case 2 packages

1. connectivity_plus: ^5.0.1
2. flutter_offline: ^2.0.0

Now **flutter_offline** was using connectivity as a dependency and because of that, I was getting this error. Because connectivity add **Reachability** and connectivity_plus add **ReachabilitySwift** in podfile.lock

```
- connectivity (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - Reachability
- connectivity_plus (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - ReachabilitySwift
```

**Solution**

So I updated both packages to the latest version, and it works for me.

1. connectivity_plus: ^5.0.1
2. flutter_offline: ^3.0.1